# Take. a particular string from a TEXT in postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have one question:
Below is an error message which is stored in a postgres table column, From this string i would like to extract only a part of the string, Is that possible to do in Postgres?

I would like to see **odoo.exceptions.ValidationError: ('No MRP template was found for MO/10881!', None)'** only this part.

In general all text starting with odoo.exceptions.ValidationError: until the end

How can i do it ? Any idea or suggestions?

```
'Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/src/addons_OCA/queue/queue_job/controllers/main.py", line 101, in runjob
    self._try_perform_job(env, job)
  File "/opt/src/addons_OCA/queue/queue_job/controllers/main.py", line 61, in _try_perform_job
    job.perform()
  File "/opt/src/addons_OCA/queue/queue_job/job.py", line 466, in perform
    self.result = self.func(*tuple(self.args), **self.kwargs)
  File "/opt/src/addons/costs/models/mrp_production.py", line 163, in trigger_calculate_all_costs
    self.calculate_all_costs()
  File "/opt/src/addons/sucosts/models/costline_mixin.py", line 284, in calculate_all_costs
    rec.generate_service_products()
  File "/opt/src/addons/mrp_product_templates/models/mrp_production.py", line 660, in generate_service_products
    MO=self.name)))
odoo.exceptions.ValidationError: ('No MRP template was found for MO/10881!', None)'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [regexp_replace](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html) function to search for particular text then *select* the text following.

> The regexp_replace function provides substitution of new text for
> substrings that match POSIX regular expression patterns. It has the
> syntax regexp_replace(source, pattern, replacement [, flags ]). The
> source string is returned unchanged if there is no match to the
> pattern. ...

In this case it seems you want the text after *ValidationError:*. Something like: (see [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=57da4a5de65eb2cfb64a9fbbd80993bc))

```
select regexp_replace (message, '.*ValidationError:(.*)','\1') 
  from test;
```